# Linq IN Clause in Where

Tags: c#, linq

I want to know how to use `IN` clause in Linq. Here is my Code :-

```
int empCount = ctx.tblEmpTran
                .Count(
                    e => e.Id == Id &&
                    e.Month == selectedMonth &&
                    e.Year == selectedYear &&
                    e.employeeId.contains()
                );
```

The Following query is supposed to be in `IN`

```
SELECT A.Id FROM dbo.EmployeeDetail A WHERE A.CompanyId = 1 AND A.COLS > 0
```

In the above code, `contains` method do not popup in intellisense.

Comment: it is called "Any". Actually Any for exists and contains for In.

Comment: where is the employeeDetail dbset, have you set the relations between two models.

Comment: @Anup if by general convention, e.employeeId is numeric(int/long) then also intellisense don't show Contains() method. Contains() method is available on string/collection types.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to convert from SQL to Linq, and you couldn't try a worse approach.

You should try to write your LINQ query starting from what you need it to do, forgetting SQL altogether.

In Linq there is no "IN" operator, to achieve the same thing you take your collection and check if it `Contains` the value.

So in your scenario you should simply generate your collection of valid values and then in your query do:

```
myCollection.Contains(e.employeeId)
```

It is "collection CONTAINS value" the logic, not "value is found IN collection". Again if you insist to start from SQL when using Linq you will always incur in this kind of problems.

Check Albahari tutorial on [how to approach Linq correctly](http://www.linqpad.net/MasteringLINQ.aspx) and your productivity will skyrocket.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a collection of employee IDs that you want to check, and the code would be

```
employees.contains(e.employeeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this `e.employeeId.contains()`, you should use this:

```
listOfIds.Contains(e.employeeId)
```

where `listOfIds` would be a list of int, `List<int>` and would contain the ids you would place between the parentheses after `IN(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

considering that you have a tblEmployeeDetail in the same DbSet and them having a relation through employeeId you can write you query like.

```
var q = from e in ctx.tblEmployeeDetail where e.Transactions.Any(t => t.Month == selectedMonth &&
                    t.Year == selectedYear);
int empCount = q.Count();
```

this is pseudo-code but this is how you would use the LINQ effectively, (Exists is better than In check)